# How to strip everything between a key phrase and an ending tag?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to strip everything between a key phrase and ending tag but for some reason it is not working. I always get blank data. I've tried many different ways but no luck.

Basically I have a script that connect to IMAP and store emails into MySQL as service tickets. It works great but I am trying to strip off everything except for user reply because currently if a user reply to an email it re-inserts the entire email into MySQL. I added a key phrase at the top of all outgoing emails .

1. Structure is as below:

   ```
    --Reply below this line to respond--
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Email body message...
   ```
2. When replying to the message, it becomes:

   ```
   New Message reply......

   --Reply below this line to respond--

   old message body.
   ```
3. I would only like to insert the new reply message only.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$message = strip_tags($message, "<br><div><p><u><hr></section>");

$message=preg_replace("</p>", "br /", $message);

$message=preg_replace('#--REPLY above this line to respond--(.*?)</section>)#s', ' ', $message);

$message=clean("<br/><hr><u>Received On $rep_date / $from_email</u><br><br/>$message");
```

It inserts the Received On date and From but `$message` is blank.

If I remove `$message=preg_replace('#--REPLY` above this line to `respond--(.*?)</section>)#s', ' ', $message);` it inserts the entire email.

Any suggestion on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `/--(.*)/s` is this what you are asking?

Comment: `$message = preg_replace("</p>", "br /", $message)` rings alarm bells in my mind. Certainly, it works, but I seriously doubt you can tell me why you need to use `br /` and not `<br />`.

Comment: can you give a real example and what you actually want to remove? what you are asking is confusing

Comment: I know it is a bit confusing. I will update my question in a sec. thanks so much.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am using br because for some reason when replying using outlook it replaces <br/> with <<br/>>

Comment: @user3620142 Exactly. You don't know. It's because your regex is looking for `/p`. Because `<` and `>` are being treated as delimiters. You have no idea what you're doing here, and that's dangerous...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regular expressions.  [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) should work find in this scenario.

```
// After cleaning the message...
$message_parts = explode("--Reply below this line to respond--", $message, 2);
$message = $message_parts[0];
```

If you do feel the need to use regular expressions, you can use [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) instead of explode.  Using regular expressions may be more helpful if you need case insensitivity or other such niceties.

**edit:**  Hah!  You search for "Reply *above* this line", but the message contains "Reply *below* this line".
You'll never match it if you're searching for the wrong string.

Here's an example of the fixed version: http://ideone.com/gL9awc

Comment: i tried your recommendations but it still keeps on inserting blank :( any other suggestions?

Comment: woops, sorry my mistake with above and below.. should be above. i am reviewing your demo, thank you so much. will let you know if i get it to work on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm we can use the keywords and the substr function to extract the information you want:

```
$message = substr($message, strpos($message,'New Message'), strpos($message,'--Reply') );
```